# Is it possible to know the position of MOM?

Tags: mars, isro, mars-orbiter-mission

- How far has the MOM (Mars Orbiter Mission) travelled, and
- Where is it now?

It is scheduled to reach Mars orbit on September 1 this year.

Comment: http://sankara.net/mom.html

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks for the link but I think this does not provide the true data.The official website of [MOM](http://www.isro.org/mars/updates.aspx) shows till 12-06-2014 it has crossed 466 million KM but in the website you have provided shows only 2.88 million has crossed

Comment: Click on the "Now" button to see where the vehicles are now.

Comment: @DavidHammen The site is created by a person who is not asscoiated with MOM project.So I guess the data isnt true and accurate.The person has only created a simulator/animation as I can see from the person linked profile https://www.linkedin.com/in/kvsankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only to provide some supplemental information on the discussion in the comments section of the original question.

There was a reference to an animation of the MOM and MAVEN orbits at http://sankara.net/mom.html . Since I am the developer of the animation, I would like to clarify a few things:

- The animation uses orbit data fetched from NASA JPL's [HORIZONS](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) web interface
- For the Mars Orbiter Mission, JPL publishes the information obtained from its Deep Space Network and/or the Indian Space Research Organization
- I update the animation whenever JPL publishes an update on HORIZONS. So the metrics reported by the animation are perhaps the best available publicly.
- I believe NASA Eyes must be using orbit data from a source equivalent to HORIZONS
- As of September 2014, the animation reports distances from Sun, Earth, and Mars. Not the distance traveled since launch.

Answer (score 5):

Download [Eyes on the Solar System](http://eyes.nasa.gov/).  Mars Orbiter Mission is one of the spacecraft tracked therein.  It looks to be a little behind MAVEN, also tracked.  The measuring tools can tell you how far away it is from anything else that's tracked, like the Sun, Earth, Mars, and MAVEN.

Clicking on additional information button in its toolbar, it displays an external link to [ISRO's Mars Orbiter Mission page](http://www.isro.org/mars/updates.aspx), with regular mission updates. Currently latest is from ten days ago as of writing this answer (12-06-2014):

> At present, the radio distance between the Spacecraft and the Earth is
>   102 million km. A radio signal from the Earth to the Spacecraft now
>   takes about 340 seconds. The spacecraft so far has traveled a distance
>   of 466 million km as part of its total Journey of 680 million km.

For current distance to Earth, you can also use [DSN Now](http://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html) online tool and click on the DSN (Deep Space Network) station that tracks MOM at that time. When available, the range is displayed in the right column.

Comment: And thanks to @TildalWave for the other two links.